# DMA memory (first 2 GB)

Tags: linux-device-driver, dma, pci

I would like to alloc memory for a dma transfer between a PCI device and RAM. I am using the next function in order to alloc memory:

```
pci_alloc_consistent
```

I want to alloc memory under 2GB. Otherwise, the pci device fail. But this function provides any address from my ram (4GB). Are there any solution?

BR

Answer (score 2):

You can call `pci_set_coherent_dma_mask` on the `struct pci_dev *`, or preferably call `dma_set_coherent_mask` on `pcidev->dev` to set the mask. Setting the mask to `DMA_BIT_MASK(31)` will restrict coherent mappings to the first 2 GiB.  For consistency, you might also want to restrict the non-coherent mappings by calling `pci_set_dma_mask` or `dma_set_mask`.

A good place to call the above functions is from your PCI driver "probe" function.

Comment: I think you sound too technical, and something like "the change should be done in PCI part of the driver in question" should be added.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko, I added a paragraph about where to call the functions from. Sorry about sounding "too technical". I aimed it at a somewhat technical audience - if the audience is writing code to perform DMA transfers, that counts as "somewhat technical" in my book!

Comment: I don't know how long your are here at SO (a-ha, less than a year), but from my experience I could tell that here many people who kinda first time programming in Linux kernel environment. And sometimes it's a burden to get that person doesn't know much after few ping-pong comments... Seems like SO has a lack of good assumption engine to search duplicates (or at least I don't know about) since too many of them often asked similar questions again and again.